# Passing potentially undefined parameters as function arguments

Tags: php

I have a function that retrieves images based on the filters that are passed to it.

```
function getImgs($one = NULL,$two = NULL,$three = NULL,$four = NULL) {}
```

I call this by

```
$img->getImgs($_GET['one'],$_GET['two'],$_GET['three'],$_GET['four']);
```

These parameters don't necessarily have to exist though and therefore they may be undefined when they are passed through.

I'd like to pass each parameter through if it exists, if not then do not pass it through. How would I go about that? Can I `= NULL` them when they are being passed in some way?

Comment: try this `$one = ""`

Comment: You have to check them before you pass them to the function, otherwise you will get some notices

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju the function works, if I don't pass `$one` through then the function will recognise that. It's more - if it doesn't exist in the first place, don't pass it through that I want to achieve.

Comment: ok ok.why dont you send in `array()`??

Comment: I agree with @NiranjanNRaju, just pass an array to the function and iterate the array.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Didn't occur to me! I'll go with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this works:

```
$img->getImgs(($_GET['one']?$_GET['one']:NULL),($_GET['two']?$_GET['two']:NULL),($_GET['three']?$_GET['three']:NULL),($_GET['four']?$_GET['four']:NULL));
```

If you use error logging you may see that it raises some warnings about undefined variables, this solution prevents crashes/not-functioning code, it does not prevent logging.
This also assumes that the variables are not `FALSE, NULL, 0, array(), ''` or any other form of values of zero, null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that checks params, like this:

```
function getQueryParam($index)
{
    return isset($_GET[$index])?$_GET[$index]:null;
}
//then call you function like this
$img->getImgs(getQueryParam('one'),getQueryParam('two'),getQueryParam('three'),getQueryParam('four'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an array:

```
function getImgs($imgArr) {
    foreach($imgArray as $key => $val){
        if(!empty($val)){
        // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow you to only work with the items that are passed in via `$_GET`.

`$img->getImgs($_GET);`